what is the preferred-data-persistence-auth-method for using access token(connetion string) as authentication method in redis cache
I am changing the authentication method of a redis resource from managedidentity to access token
what should be added in redis config PreferredDataPersistenceAuthMethod.
Currently it is
"preferred-data-persistence-auth-method": "ManagedIdentity"
whst should be the "preferred-data-persistence-auth-method" while using connection string(access token) as a auth method


What should be the "preferred-data-persistence-auth-method" while using a connection string (access token) as an auth method?

According to this Github-Document, the preferred-data-persistence-auth-method is used to communicate with the storage account for data persistence, either by SAS or Managed identity.

If changing the authentication method of a Redis resource from managed identity to connection string, what should be added in the Redis config PreferredDataPersistenceAuthMethod?

To authenticate with a storage account connection string, use the following PowerShell command to modify the RedisConfiguration:
Command and output:
PS /home/venkatesan> Set-AzRedisCache -ResourceGroupName "v-xxx" -Name "xxx" -RedisConfiguration @{"rdb-backup-enabled" = "true"; "rdb-storage-connection-string" = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat123;AccountKey=MnvIVSoYyxxxxxad+G9+SrsS+AStxf+aMQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"; "rdb-backup-frequency" = "30"}

Name                   : sampleredis1
Id                     : /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Cache/Redis/sampleredis1
Location               : East US
Type                   : Microsoft.Cache/Redis
HostName               : sampleredis1.redis.cache.windows.net
Port                   : 6379
ProvisioningState      : Succeeded
SslPort                : 6380
RedisConfiguration     : {[rdb-backup-enabled, true], [rdb-backup-frequency, 30], [rdb-storage-connection-string, DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=venkat123;AccountKey=[key hidden]], [aof-backup-enabled, false]…}
EnableNonSslPort       : False
RedisVersion           : 6.0
Size                   : 6GB
Sku                    : Premium
ResourceGroupName      : xxxx
IdentityType           : 
SystemAssignedIdentity : 
UserAssignedIdentity   : 
PrimaryKey             : ATlKxxxxx
SecondaryKey           : rBXHGXs2z3zxxxxxxx
SubnetId               : 
StaticIP               : 
TenantSettings         : 
ShardCount             : 
Tag                    : {}
Zone                   : 


Portal:

Reference:
Set-AzRedisCache (Az.RedisCache) | Microsoft Learn

how to set exisiting user assigned managed identity as null
